# How to inherit some of propery of parent class

Tags: c#, oop, class, c#-4.0, object

Please Consider this scenario:

We have a base class called `clsMain` :

```
class clsMain
{
    int P1{set; get;}
    int P2{set; get;}
    int P3{set; get;}
    string P4{set; get;}
    string P5{set; get;}
}
```

and I want to have these 2 obejcts from `clsMain` :

```
object1 psudo code:
{
    int P1{set; get;}
    int P2{set; get;}
    int P3{set; get;}    
}
```

and :

```
object2 psudo code:
{
    int P3{set; get;}
    string P4{set; get;}
    string P5{set; get;}
}
```

is it possible in c#? should I use specific type of class(abstract,...)?

thanks a lot

Comment: do yuo want that clases hav that properties esclusively?

Comment: Tigran's Answer below, looks real good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance is possible in C# as a first-class concept:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string Name { get { return "Adam"; } }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public override string Name { get { return "Foo"; } }
}
```

To `override` something, you need to make it `virtual` and needs to have accessibility of anything other than `private`.

In your instance you could possibly do something like:

```
class clsMain
{
    public virtual int P1{set; get;}
    public virtual int P2{set; get;}
    public virtual int P3{set; get;}
    public virtual string P4{set; get;}
    public virtual string P5{set; get;}
}

class object1 : clsMain
{
    public override int P1{set; get;}
    public override int P2{set; get;}
    public override int P3{set; get;}    
}

class object2 : clsMain
{
    public override int P3{set; get;}
    public override string P4{set; get;}
    public override string P5{set; get;}
}
```

Though if I'm being honest, your question isn't very clear. Note, however, that C# does not support multiple inheritance of classes.

Sounds like you want to filter out the properties. You cannot stop inherited members from being accessed (well, there is the `new` modifier, but this is sketchy at best).  Instead you can use interfaces:

```
interface Iobject1
{
    int P1 { set; get; }
    int P2 { set; get; }
    int P3 { set; get; } 
}

interface Iobject2
{
    int P3{set; get;}
    string P4{set; get;}
    string P5{set; get;}
}

class clsMain : Iobject1, Iobject2
{
    public int P1{set; get;}
    public int P2{set; get;}
    public int P3{set; get;}
    public string P4{set; get;}
    public string P5{set; get;}
}
```

Comment: thanks dear @Adam Houldsworth. but when I create object based on object2 I see `clsMAin` proprties.I want a thing like Sql view

Comment: @Kerezo You cannot hide members. What you can do instead is make interfaces that only expose the members you want and talk to the interface instead.

Answer (score 1):

In this case in base class leave only *shared* properties, like this pseudocode:

```
class clsMain
{   
    int P3{set; get;}   
}

class object1 : clsMain
{
    int P1{set; get;}
    int P2{set; get;}   
}

class object2 : clsMain
{    
    string P4{set; get;}
    string P5{set; get;}
}
```

Comment: wasn't me, but I'm guessing it was because your posted code isn't valid C#.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: the original code wasn't too :) so I just followed the same concept.. bah. The question is conceptual so the answer too..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear ... You can't inherit from 2 object in C#

If you want clsMain to have all properties herited from object1 and object2, what you can do is:

- object2 inherit from object1
- clsMain inherit from object2

So clsMain will have all properties from object1 and object2

Using abstract just protect the class from being created directly. If you put object1 as abstract, you'll never be able to do "var x = new object1();"

EDIT: I forgot to say that properties must be protected or public, otherwise they are not accessible from the derived class.